# Kronecker delta representation of a matrix (Quantum raising / lowering operators)

Tags: tensor-products, tensors, quantum-mechanics, differential-operators, kronecker-product

The Kronecker Delta is commonly used to represent a diagonal matrix:
$$
a_i \delta_{ij}=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a_1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & a_2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & a_3
\end{array}\right)
$$
for 3 dimensions (not Einstein Summation).

However, in Quantum Mechanics, or more specifically the book by Griffith, the Kronecker Delta was used to represent a"shifted" diagonal matrices, i.e.:
$$
a_-=\sqrt{n'}\delta_{n,n'-1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{4} & ...\\
. & . & . & . & . & ...
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where $n$ is the row index and $n'$ is the column index, and both $n$ and $n'$ begin from 0 (so the upper left entry is $n=0, n'=0$).

Now I was wondering if there are algebraic properties for the Kronecker Delta used in this way.  If I multiplied two matrices in their Kronecker Delta form, is there a way to get the solution using simple manipulations of the Kronecker Deltas and their indices?

For example, computing something like:
$$
(a_{-})^l(a_{+})^m
$$
where $a_{+}$ is $(a_{-})^\dagger$ (conjugate transpose of the lowering operator), or
$$
a_+=\sqrt{n}\delta_{n',n-1}=\sqrt{n'}\delta_{n,n'+1}=
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
\sqrt{1} & 0 & 0 & 0 & ...\\
0 & \sqrt{2} & 0 & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & ...\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \sqrt{4} & ...\\
. & . & . & . & ...
\end{array}
\right)
$$

I worked out $(a_+)^m$ by taking successive products of $a_+$ and got the following by inspecting the pattern:

$$
(a_+)^m=\sqrt{\frac{(n'+m)!}{n'!}}\delta_{n,n'+m}=\sqrt{\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}}\delta_{n',n-m}
$$
where if I had, for example:
$$
(a_+)^3 = \sqrt{n}\delta_{n,n'+1}\sqrt{n'}\delta_{n',n''+1}\sqrt{n''}\delta_{n'',n'''+1}=\sqrt{n'''+3}\sqrt{n'''+2}\sqrt{n'''+1}\delta_{n,n'''+3}
$$
I would systematically eliminate each delta by setting the delta indexes belonging to one delta equal to one another (and eliminating the "repeated" indices), until I am left with two indices, namely $n$ and $n'''$, and checking that it gives the correct matrix.

$n'=n''+1=n'''+2$

This is too tedious to do for the general case, and I haven't explored multiplication of non-identical matrices.

I was wondering if there are rules from, perhaps, Tensor Analysis that makes this easier.

---

For reference, $a_-$ is the lowering operator in the system of one electron in a Simple Harmonic Oscillator potential $V = \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2$, and in terms of momentum $p$ and position $x$,

$$
a_-=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2m\hbar\omega}}(ip+m\omega x)
$$
and $p = -i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in position space.  $a_-$ acts on a SHO energy eigenstate $|\psi_{n}>$ and lowers it:
$$
a_-|\psi_{n}>=\sqrt{n}|\psi_{n-1}>
$$